# I am using paypal_base.jar & paypal_stubs.jar that were created in 2009, will these get deprecated by the Paypal of June 17th?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using CallerServices &  CertificateAPIProfile from the paypal_base.jar, and I am using a bunch of SOAP methods from the paypal_stubs.jar.  Getting worried about this deadline, not sure if these are affected or not.

Answer (score 0):

You must fix your app before June 17th as paypal will stop to use  TLS 1.0 that is the only protocol supported by that jar version. 
https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1914&viewlocale=en_US

Here you can find a replacement for that jar supplied by PayPal:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Legacy-Java-SDK